# Map from Rc<RefCell<T>> to Ref<'_, U>

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker, reference-counting, borrowing

I have the following structures:

```rust
struct Inner;

enum State {
    A(Inner),
    B,
}

struct Owner {
    state: Rc<RefCell<State>>,
}
```

And I would like to provide the following interface:

```rust
impl Owner {
    fn a(&self) -> Option<Ref<'_, Inner>>;
}
```

Where `owner.a()` would return:

- When `owner.state` matches `State::A(s)`, then `Some([some ref to s])` (which increments the strong count of `owner.state` and decrements it when dropped, while guaranteeing `RefCell` borrowing properties);
- Otherwise, `None`.

Is this at all possible? I've tried looking at `Ref::map` but I can't seem to make it work with `Rc<RefCell<_>>` and `Option`.

What I'm doing right now instead as a workaround is:

```rust
impl Owner {
    fn with_a(&self, mut callback: impl FnMut(&Inner)) {
        match *self.state.borrow() {
            State::A(ref inner) => callback(inner),
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=00060c9d5c12a4fba7e258d336e9f953)

Comment: You mention wanting to increment the count on the Rc, but `fn a(&self) -> Option<Ref<'_, Inner>>;` would tie the lifetime of the ref to the Rc anyway so there is no need to increment the count. If the function signature you posted is more what you want, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=cbe6dba3deb26217d81f1011bf4c8b3c would work.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I was missing the `unreachable!` part, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`owner.a()` doesn't need to increment the `Rc`'s strong count since the returned `Ref`'s lifetime is already tied to the `Rc`. If you're working with 100% Safe Rust and it compiles you won't have any memory safety issues, so you don't have to worry about manual bookkeeping like explicitly incrementing or decrementing an `Rc`'s strong count. `Rc` doesn't even expose methods to change the strong count and for good reason. Here's the implementation for the function signature you want:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::{RefCell, Ref};

struct Inner;

enum State {
    A(Inner),
    B,
}

struct Owner {
    state: Rc<RefCell<State>>,
}

impl Owner {
    fn a(&self) -> Option<Ref<'_, Inner>> {
        let state_ref = self.state.borrow();
        match *state_ref {
            State::B => None,
            _ => Some(Ref::map(state_ref, |state| match state {
                State::A(inner) => inner,
                _ => unreachable!(),
            })),
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=1c6b3a6f0aba1b0af3e01376176a2b7d)

Comment: That did the trick! I also found [ref_map_filter](https://crates.io/crates/ref_filter_map) crate which avoids the double match. Marking this as the accepted answer since I can't accept @loganfsmyth's comment.